# Combining three tables with two dynamic values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a database for a guessing game where a player should guess the value of a given product. I have three tables;

One table for the products with the following columns:

- ProductID
- ProductName (VarChar)

One table for the players with the following columns

- PlayerID
- PlayerName (VarChar)

One table where the players, the products and their guesses are stored, i.e

- GuessID
- PlayerID
- ProductID
- Guess (Int)

I'm an trying to find a way to combine which player (PlayerName) that made the highest guess (Guess) for EVERY product (ProductName), i.e a way to summarize every single product, the highest guess for each product and the name och player who made the guess.

So far, I have only been able to get the correct ProductName and the correct Guess-value for each product. Somehow this doesn't work for PlayerName and i keep getting the wrong Name each time.

```
SELECT pl.PlayerName, MAX(g.Guess), p.ProductName
FROM 
    guess g
    INNER JOIN player pl on g.PlayerID = pl.PlayerID
    INNER JOIN product p on g.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY g.ProductID;
```

I guess my problem is that each row related to a specific product holds two dynamic values; Guess and PlayerID which is giving me problems whenever i try to sort by Max(Guess). I can't make any sense of the PlayerID that is chosen for the query stated above. It doesn't make any sense to me.

I would appreciate if any of you guys could point me in the right direction.

Cheers.

Comment: " It doesn't make any sense to me. " Because your query does not make sense because it's not ANSI SQL.. Used non aggregated columns in the SELECT clause should also be in the GROUP BY clause  to be ANSi SQL valid.. MySQL extends the GROUP BY with a "feature" where this is not required but can cause invalid data.

Comment: .. The more modern MySQL versions it is possible to disable the extended GROUP BY feature with a sql_mode called ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY..  Besidesi advice you to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide us with example data and expected results.

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you are trying to do, but I believe you need to do this recursively or with 2 queries and a temp table. When I am trying to solution complicated queries I will generally write multiple simple queries and then look for the best way to combine them. In your case you can select the max guess for each product, then use that result to query for who made that max guess. You'll have to deal with things like what happens when 2 players had the same max guess, etc. that you aren't dealing with now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery to select the highest guess for each product, then select the related players and products records in the outer query, like :

```
SELECT 
    p.productname, u.playername, g.guess as "max guess" 
FROM 
    guess_table g
    INNER JOIN product_table p ON p.productid = g.productid
    INNER JOIN players_table u on u.playerid = g.playerid
WHERE g.guess = (SELECT MAX(guess) FROM guess_table WHERE productid = p.productid)
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! It makes more sense than using 'group by', now that I have the correct query :). Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of last value in this query. You can also use first value by ordering desc (you don't have to give unbounded preceding and following. Also, this is based on assumption that guess is unique within product name, so that ordering will be consistent.

Sample data and output would have helped to see if it is expected or not  but I think it will work here based on what you have mentioned.

```
SELECT distinct   p.ProductName,
last_value(Guess) over (partition by p.ProductName order by Guess  rows between 
unbounded preceding and unbounded following )  GuessNumber, 
last_value(pl.PlayerName) over (partition by p.ProductName order by Guess rows 
between unbounded preceding and unbounded following ) PlayerName
FROM guess g
inner join player pl on g.PlayerID = pl.PlayerID
inner join product p on g.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Comment: Windows functions only work in MySQL 8.0+ by the way you forget to mention that..

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use something of a hack in MySQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(pl.PlayerName ORDER BY g.guess DESC), ',', 1) as PlayerName,
       MAX(g.Guess), p.ProductName
FROM guess g JOIN
     player pl
     ON g.PlayerID = pl.PlayerID JOIN
     product p 
     ON g.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY p.ProductName;
```

This method definitely has limits.  The internal string representation for `GROUP_CONCAT()` is limited to about 1000 characters (although that can be expanded).  The above assumes that the names do not contain commas (although other separators can be used).

The better solution is to use window functions, but these are available only in MySQL 8+.